# Excel Graduated Tier Pricing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am needing pointers in creating a graduated tier pricing formula. What I am needing to show is 1-5 units costs $0.10, 6-9 cost $.20, 10-14 cost $0.30 and 15+ cost $0.40. With the graduated prices 6 units costs $0.70, that is 5 units at $0.10 each ($0.50) and 1 unit at $0.20 for a total of $0.70. I am looking at sumproduct with an if statement but nothing I am coming up with is working.

```
Units   Cost     Total Cost 
1    $0.10   $0.10 
2    $0.10   $0.20 
3    $0.10   $0.30 
4    $0.10   $0.40 
5    $0.10   $0.50 
6    $0.20   $0.70 
7    $0.20   $0.90 
8    $0.20   $1.10 
9    $0.20   $1.30 
10   $0.30   $1.60 
11   $0.30   $1.90 
12   $0.30   $2.20 
13   $0.30   $2.50 
14   $0.30   $2.80 
15   $0.40   $3.50
```

Comment: Why are you selling 6 items for 10¢ more than two sales of 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My version of the formula (number of units in A2)

```
=A2*0.1 + MAX(0,A2-5)*0.1 + MAX(0,A2-9)*0.1 + MAX(0,A2-14)*0.1
```

5, 9 and 14 constants in the formula are the upper bounds of each range.

Comment: Wow - too cool. Didnt think the MAX function could do that! This works too, I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Question for you, it looks like its not adding the increments correctly. I tweaked the formula to have my $0.50 as my range for 1-25, 26-50 at $.10, when I have that its giving the total as $13.50 instead of $12.60                          =B2*0.5 + MAX(0,B2-25)*0.5 + MAX(0,B2-50)*0.5+MAX(0,B2-100)*0.5+MAX(0,B2-500)*0.5+MAX(0,B2-1000)*0.5+MAX(0,B2-5000)*0.5

Comment: @Daniel Strong - in your sample data the price in each range went up by 0.10. So there is `*0.1` after each max function in my answer. This should be the difference between current range and previous. So if you want the price for 1-25 to be 0.50, and 0.10 for 26-50, the formula should be `=B2*0.5 + MAX(0,B2-25)*(-0.40)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a formula for the total cost, where the `A` column is the number of units, starting at `A1=1`, `A2=2`, etc.

```
=IF(A1<6,A1*0.1,IF(A1<10,0.5+(A1-5)*0.2,IF(A1<15,1.3+(A1-9)*0.3,2.8+(A1-14)*0.4)))
```

This gives the same answers as your question, except for 15 @ $3.50, which I'm assuming is a typo (15 units should be $3.20).

If you also need the middle `Cost` column, you should be able to simplify this formula to create it.

Comment: Awesome! That works, I appreciate the help, this was driving me insane! :)